# Checking sum in SQL vs .Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash

I can do a checksum for a table in sql like this,

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) from Table_1;
```

and store it in another table we use to keep hash of certain tables + columns

I am assuming it's possible to do same with .Net too ?

I know of md5 hashing algorithm but I ***think*** it that doesn't returns a big int like SQL checksum does so that we can checksum whole table.

Are there any benefits of doing this in SQL ? like performance etc.. I tested SQL checksum with 100,000 records and it's instant but not sure how to test it with .Net

Comment: Well to hash 100k records in a .Net client you have to read, return, update and resend 100k records over the wire which is certainly going to be slower than doing it in situ with a T-SQL function (or CLR procedure)

Comment: The hash algorithm can use : <algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512 (I think the 1st is the default).  The msdn documentation say hash max are 8000 bytes I think number of bytes in a row (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql).  Also see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql